# Chrome Dev Tools - Emulation View keeps showing on open

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

EVerytime i press F12 to open the Dev Tools on Chrome, i get the stupid emulation panel
[image]
I also go into the Settings and Overrides, and uncheck the Show Emulation View in console drawer, and then reload the page, and it still keeps showing up.

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug and it has been fixed, so please wait for the next update.